# Allow user to edit profile information and submit it causing page to redirect to profile page.

Tags: python, django, url, jinja2

In django I am attempting to allow that user to edit his/her profile information, press submit, and have the the change reflect in his/her profile page.

This is the code :

In the views.py document in my application

> User is allowed to view the profile page

```
def view_profile(request):

    var = { 'user' : request.user }

    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', var)
```

> User is allowed to edit the profile page

```
def edit_profile(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserChangeForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return redirect('account/profile')

    else:

        form = UserChangeForm(instance=request.user)

        var = {'form' : form }
        return render(request, 'accounts/edit_profile.html', var)
```

This is the urls.py document

> Import modules

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
```

> Defined the urls

```
urlpatterns = [

url(r'^profile/$', views.view_profile, name = 'view_profile'),  
url(r'^profile/edit/$', views.edit_profile, name = 'edit_profile')

]
```

This is the edit_profile

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{%  block head %}

<title>{{ user }}</title>

{% endblock %}


{%  block body %}

<div class = "container">

<form method = "post">

    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.as_p }}

    <button class = "btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

When I edit user model on the `edit_profile.html` page and submit, it redirects

from :

http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/profile/edit/

To :

http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/profile/edit/account/profile

This latter urls is not accurate, it should redirect

To :

http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/profile

This is how that page looks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect you should include a leading slash to make it an absolute url:

```
return redirect('/account/profile')
```

You can avoid hardcoding the url by using the URL pattern name instead. The `redirect` shortcut will reverse the url for you:

```
return redirect('view_profile')
```